# Jasmine test on Ember.js Model with reopenClass

Tags: ember.js, jasmine

My model looks like:

```
  App.MyUser = Ember.Object.extend();
  App.MyUser.reopenClass({
    attribute1: '',
    attribute2: '',
    getFunction: function() {
       ...
    },
    setFunction: function(foo) {
       ...
    }
  });
```

How to test the functions in jasmine?

```
   describe( "The user model", function () {  
               var user = null;
            App = Ember.Application.create();
            beforeEach(function(){
                user = App.MyUser.create();      
            });

            afterEach(function(){
                user = null;
            });

            it("should have an get function", function(){
                expect(user.getFunction).toBeDefined();
            });
        });
```

But I always get:

```
 Expected undefined to be defined.
```

If I do my model like this:

```
 App.MyUser = Ember.Object.extend({......
```

without reopenClass it works fine. But i need to use reopenClass. So how does it work?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to create `App.User` but you have defined `App.MyUser`

Comment: Why do you say you need to use reopenClass? It seems that you want to add instance methods, not class methods.